# Python default logger disabled

Tags: python, logging

For some reason, in a Python application I am trying to modify, the logger is not logging anything. I traced the error to `logging/__init__.py`

```
def handle(self, record):
    """
    Call the handlers for the specified record.

    This method is used for unpickled records received from a socket, as
    well as those created locally. Logger-level filtering is applied.
    """
    if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
        self.callHandlers(record)
```

I am not sure why, but `self.disabled` is `True`. Nowhere in the application this value is set and I don't think any of the packages is changing it. The logger is instantiated as usual `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`. When I set `logger.disabled = False` before actually logging anything (before calling `logger.info()`), the logger prints the expected log text. But if I don't, it returns in `handle()` without logging anything.

Is there any way I can debug this? Perhaps one can change the `Logger` class so that some function is called whenever `disabled` gets written to...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need to trace what code might set `handler.disabled` to True (it is 0, so false, by default), you can replace the attribute with a property:

```
import logging
import sys

@property
def disabled(self):
    try:
        return self._disabled
    except AttributeError:
        return False

@disabled.setter
def disabled(self, disabled):
    if disabled:
        frame = sys._getframe(1)
        print(
            f"{frame.f_code.co_filename}:{frame.f_lineno} "
            f"disabled the {self.name} logger"
        )
    self._disabled = disabled

logging.Logger.disabled = disabled
```

Demo from the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger('foo.bar').disabled = True
<stdin>:1 disabled the foo.bar logger
```

If you want to see the full stack, add `from traceback import print_stack`, and inside the `if disabled:` block, `print_stack(frame)`.

Answer (score 21):

Often found this problem when [configuration schema](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging) is used, by default **disable_existing_loggers** is *True* so all loggers that not included in that schema will be disabled.

BTW Martin Pieters' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28694704/5274713) is supreme and works in any situation when you've stuck.